# Does type signature matter when using QObject::connect() , For connecting a function to a signal?

Tags: c++, qt, function

I'm trying to connect a user-defined function with QComboBox activated() signal, like so(in mainwindow.cpp):

```
QObject::connect(ui->comboBox, SIGNAL(activated(QString)), obj.sChange());
```

And after that defining sChange function:

```
void MainWindow::sChange(QString str)
    {
        //Some code here.
    }
```

Its giving me an error at QObject::connect() line, that says *Invalid use of void expression*.
What am I doing wrong??

EDIT: Here's my complete mainwindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    //void sChange(QString);

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

public slots:
    void sChange(QString);
};
```

Comment: You're passing the return value of `obj.sChange()` as the third parameter to `connect`. The return type of `sChange` is `void`. Engage facepalm.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious lol? so i tried `SLOT(obj.sChange())` but it still doesn't seem to call sChange() function. Any guess why??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
QObject::connect(ui->comboBox, SIGNAL(activated(QString)), this, SLOT(sChange(QString)));
```

and make sure MainWindow has the Q_OBJECT macro at the top of the class, and that in the header sChange() is declared as public slots: (or protected or whatever). I'm assuming this connection is done somewhere in main windows code, otherwise replace 'this' with a pointer to MainWindow.

Also, you may need to do &ui->comboBox if thats an instance of a comboBox and not a pointer to one.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but when I run the program, it says `No such slot Mainwindow::sChange() in MyProject` Any idea what's wrong ??

Comment: Make sure that in the main windows class, it's declared in a section that has the 'slots' keyword, i.e. public slots:

Comment: @NicolasHothaus Yes, it is in the public slots: in MainWindow class, but still not working. And it still says No such slot during runtime :(

Comment: Do you have the Q_OBJECT macro in your main window class?

Comment: Yes, you can now see my whole mainwindow.h, edited the question.

Comment: lol, So stupid of myself, I just forgot to put QString in side the brackets. Anyways, Thanks dude!

Answer (score 2):

Qt supports different ways to connect signals and slots:

```
connect(ui->comboBox, SIGNAL(activated(QString)), this, SLOT(sChange(QString)));
```

or

```
connect(ui->comboBox, &QComboBox::activated, this, &MainWindow::sChange);
```

The later syntax is new in Qt 5 and requires C++11.